# Amazon S3 Bucket data transfer charges applicable while mounted in EC2 server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have created an S3 Bucket and mounted into one of my EC2 servers in the same region. Then I put data into the bucket using FTP account created for that EC2 instance. Finally, I access the data by Http request.

I'm not accessing S3 bucket directly from Internet, either for writing or accessing. All the data transferred through EC2 instance.

```
So, I assume per month charges as below, for fully used up 1TB S3 bucket (standard storage),
Storage Pricing - $0.0300*1024 = $30.72
Request Pricing - $0.005*10 = $0.05 (Assumed 10,000 request per month )
Data Transfer Pricing - Nill (Since the bucket is not being accessed directly)
```

Is that correct? or data transfer pricing is applicable?

Ref: [Pricing Details](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not pay for data transfer between S3 and EC2 in the same region, however you pay for Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Internet or EC2 instance in a different availability zone in the same region.

See [EC2 pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) for more details.

If you transfer 1TB of data OUT to Internet from AWS, either directly from S3 or through EC2 instance, you will pay the same price.

**TIP:**

If you are transferring big amount of data from S3 out to Internet, look into CloudFront. Data transfer EC2/S3/ELB -> CloudFront is free of charge and CloudFront has cheaper rates per Gb compared to downloading files directly from S3.

EDIT:

see @Michael - sqlbot's comment, this is often but not always true depending on S3 Bucket's region and CloudFront edge location serving the content.

**TIP 2:**

For really large amounts of data it might be worth setting up DirectConnect connection (private connection from your office / on-premise setup to AWS). Then Data Transfer becomes even cheaper per Gb, however you start paying hourly rate for your DirectConnect link. Do the math to calculate what's best for you.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: *"CloudFront has cheaper rates per Gb compared to downloading files directly from S3"* is often -- but not always -- true.  The cost of bandwidth out from CloudFront to the Internet varies by geographic edge region, independent of the EC2/S3 region sourcing the content and with different regional boundaries than the rest of AWS, and depends on the price class selected for the distribution as well.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot 100% correct, thanks for being very attentive.

Answer (score 4):

If you are reading data from S3 to your EC2 instance, and the S3 bucket is in the same region as your EC2 instance, then there are no data transfer costs.

Broken down:

1. There is no “data transfer in” costs to your EC2 instance if the data is coming from an S3 bucket in the same region: [EC2 Instance Pricing – Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)
2. There is no “data transfer out” costs from your S3 bucket if the data is going to an EC2 instance in the same region: [Cloud Storage Pricing – Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) – AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)
3. There is no "data tansfer out" costs from EC2 to S3.

More info:
https://www.quora.com/In-AWS-EC2-what-counts-towards-data-transfer-costs